# Kubernetes postgres can't access using pgadmin4 after deployment

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, pgadmin-4

I have successfully deployed postgres on my k8s cluster here details off deployment

Applying the deployment and services working correctly
The issue now is that when I try to connect with pgadmin4 I get connection timeout
Note: I'm using AWS and inbound rule to 30010 port already added

Is that a postgres issue related more than k8s means should I change some staff in the postgres hba file? if yes how can't I access it? shoud I configure that in each pod?

Comment: many factor, how you are deploying the service? how are you reaching the service? may be helpful debug `kubectl get service` and the check port, `kubectl port-forward svc/svc-name port:port` and then try to connect, are you getting timeout or auth error etc?

Comment: I'm having timeout yes